# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) DLIB PYTHON

Tags: python, dlib

I tried Dlib for first time and I got

"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

How can I solove it.

```
import numpy as np, cv2, dlib, os, pickle

path = './facedata/'
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
sp = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
model = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat')
FACE_DESC = []
FACE_NAME = []

for fn in os.listdir(path):
    if fn.endswith('.jpg'):
        img = cv2.imread(path + fn)[:, :, ::-1]
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        for k, d in enumerate(dets):
            shape = sp(img, d)
            face_desc = model.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape, 1)
            FACE_DESC.append(face_desc)
            print('loading...', fn)
            FACE_NAME.append(fn[:fn.index('_')])

    pickle.dump((FACE_DESC, FACE_NAME), open('trainset.pk', 'wb'))
```